# pointer to value in array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I need to have a pointer to a value in a const char array.  But I can't quite get it to work without errors.  Here's the code.

```
int main (void)
{
    const char *alp = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    char *ptr = &alp[3];

    printf("%s\n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit-  Sorry for not mentioning the errors.  The thing is I get tons of different errors depending on where I put different asterisks and ampersands.  There is no one particular error.  One of the more frequent ones I get says 
    "incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *'
      from 'const char';"

In the end I just want "ptr" to be equal to a pointer pointing to "D" in the array "alp".

Comment: what is it that you are not getting right?

Comment: Questions often come with question marks. What is your question? "What's wrong with my code?" isn't a valid question on SO.

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing? Can you not compile? Are they runtime errors, does it crash? What output do you expect?

Comment: Are you getting errors or warnings?

Comment: You are trying to assign a pointer to a const char to a non-const char pointer. I'm guessing the compiler is complaining about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want one character to print, change the `%s` to `%c` and dereference the pointer

```
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
```

It's true that you had a character pointer but `%s` tells printf to print from that pointer until it reads a null character. So we switch to `%c` which will print one character but it expects a value rather than a pointer to a value.

Comment: What do you mean to dereference the pointer, and which pointer?

If I change to %c I get an ERROR "assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers"  That's with the code

>>char *ptr;  
ptr = &alp[3]<<

Answer (score 2):

`alp` is a pointer to constant `char`.

`ptr` is a pointer to a non-const `char`.

If you want that to work out you would need to change `ptr` to be defined as:

```
char const * ptr = &alp[3];
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  I can't believe I didn't think to make it a const char.  Anyways thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The const is saying that you're not going to change it, but then you're trying to copy the reference to a variable without that limitation.  Instead, try:

```
const char *ptr = &alp[3];
```

But note that as other posters have already suggested, this code will give you a pointer to a string beginning with the D (e.g. DEFGHI...), not just the character D.

Comment: A pointer to a `char` and a pointer to a string (0-terminated sequence of `char`s) is exactly the same in C.

Comment: Yes I understand that - the question asks for a pointer to the D, and I am not sure if that means they want the specific character D, or the string from that point onwards.

Comment: But there is no difference. If you do `puts(ptr);` the pointer will be treated as a string. With `printf("%c\n", *ptr);`, the same pointer will act as a pointer to a single char. It's the  program logic which makes the difference.